# Calling remotely tasks deployed via a GAR file

Tags: ignite

I use `UriDeploymentSpi` bean to load GAR files from a directory in one of my nodes

I have following GAR `ignite.xml` file (took me a while to figure this one out btw, nowhere documented?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">


    <util:list id="myList" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <value>myproject.HelloWorldTask</value>
        <value>myproject.SimpleTask</value>
    </util:list>

</beans>
```

HelloWorldTask:

```
package myproject;

public class HelloWorldTask extends ComputeTaskAdapter<String, Integer> {

    static {
        System.out.println("TheGlue: Loading HelloWorldTask ");
    }

    public HelloWorldTask() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Map<? extends ComputeJob, ClusterNode> map(List<ClusterNode> nodes, @Nullable String arg) throws IgniteException {
        System.out.println("Hello from GAR file");
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Integer reduce(List<ComputeJobResult> results) throws IgniteException {
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

SimpleTask:

```
package myproject;

@ComputeTaskName("SimpleTaskName")
public class SimpleTask implements ComputeTask<String, Integer> {


    static {
        System.out.println("Loading SimpleTask");
    }

    public SimpleTask() {
    }

    @Override
    public Map<? extends ComputeJob, ClusterNode> map(List<ClusterNode> subgrid, String arg) throws IgniteException {
        System.out.println("Computing Job in SimpleTask ");
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public ComputeJobResultPolicy result(ComputeJobResult res, List<ComputeJobResult> rcvd) throws IgniteException {
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Integer reduce(List<ComputeJobResult> results) throws IgniteException {
        return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

The 2 classes can be found by Ignite (debugged through `GridUriDeploymentSpringDocument` and `GridUriDeploymentFileProcessor` and they are found and loaded). Ignite says that it found the GAR, but as far as I can see, the classes are not instantiated. No errors in the log files, no indications that the Tasks are deployed either.

I am trying to execute the following code on a node where the GAR file is not deployed (ie. client node of the cluster), but the Task is not executed on the cluster:

```
public class _03GarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Start urideployment test");

        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true); //needs to be the same as in the XML for the server
        cfg.setClientMode(true);

        try(Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg)) {
            ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forRemotes()).execute("SimpleTaskName", null);
        }

    }
}
```

Log file where I execute the `_03GarTest` class (same if I run with "`SimpleTaskName`" or "`myproject.SimpleTaskName`"), dumps the following stacktraces on the client node:

```
Exception in thread "main" class org.apache.ignite.IgniteDeploymentException: Unknown task name or failed to auto-deploy task (was task (re|un)deployed?): SimpleTaskName
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$7.apply(IgniteUtils.java:761)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$7.apply(IgniteUtils.java:759)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:877)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.execute(IgniteComputeImpl.java:154)
    at _03GarTest.main(_03GarTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteDeploymentCheckedException: Unknown task name or failed to auto-deploy task (was task (re|un)deployed?): SimpleTaskName
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:515)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.execute(IgniteComputeImpl.java:151)
    ... 6 more
```

And on the server, following logs are produced:

```
[13:13:33,057][INFO][disco-event-worker-#48%null%][GridDiscoveryManager] Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=b70dce5e-c0fd-4ffe-8dc2-b72b18db76da, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.1.26.59, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.8.103, 192.168.99.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.8.103:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /192.168.99.1:0, /10.1.26.59:0, /10.1.26.59:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.8.103:0, /192.168.99.1:0], discPort=0, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1452600812926, loc=false, ver=1.5.0#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2, isClient=true]
    [13:13:33,063][INFO][disco-event-worker-#48%null%][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=12, servers=1, clients=1, CPUs=8, heap=1.5GB]
    [13:13:33,085][WARNING][disco-event-worker-#48%null%][CourtesyConfigNotice] 

    >>> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
    >>> + Courtesy notice that joining node has inconsistent configuration. +
    >>> + Ignore this message if you are sure that this is done on purpose. +
    >>> +-------------------------------------------------------------------+
    >>> Remote Node ID: B70DCE5E-C0FD-4FFE-8DC2-B72B18DB76DA
    >>> Remote SPI with the same name is not configured: UriDeploymentSpi
    >>> => Local node:  o.a.i.spi.deployment.uri.UriDeploymentSpi

    [13:13:33,103][INFO][exchange-worker-#51%null%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=12, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, node=b70dce5e-c0fd-4ffe-8dc2-b72b18db76da]
    [13:13:33,907][INFO][disco-event-worker-#48%null%][GridDiscoveryManager] Node left topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=b70dce5e-c0fd-4ffe-8dc2-b72b18db76da, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.1.26.59, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.8.103, 192.168.99.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.8.103:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /192.168.99.1:0, /10.1.26.59:0, /10.1.26.59:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /192.168.8.103:0, /192.168.99.1:0], discPort=0, order=12, intOrder=7, lastExchangeTime=1452600812926, loc=false, ver=1.5.0#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2, isClient=true]
    [13:13:33,908][INFO][disco-event-worker-#48%null%][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=13, servers=1, clients=0, CPUs=8, heap=1.0GB]
    [13:13:33,918][INFO][exchange-worker-#51%null%][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=13, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_LEFT, node=b70dce5e-c0fd-4ffe-8dc2-b72b18db76da]
    [13:14:03,193][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#33%null%][IgniteKernal]
```

Any ideas on how to call a task deployed via a GAR file on another node?

**----UPDATE----**

As suggested in one of the answers, I have added the following code in the client

```
        System.out.println("Start urideployment test");

        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true); //needs to be the same as in the XML for the server
        cfg.setClientMode(true);

        UriDeploymentSpi deploymentSpi = new UriDeploymentSpi();

        deploymentSpi.setUriList(Arrays.asList("file:///Users/sbeaupre/Dropbox/prorabel/Projects/IgniteTests/ignite/gar"));

        cfg.setDeploymentSpi(deploymentSpi);

        try(Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg)) {
...
```

But this doesn't work either, I got following stack trace on the client node and nothing on the server node:

```
Jan 14, 2016 5:42:23 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: Topology snapshot [ver=4, servers=1, clients=1, CPUs=8, heap=1.5GB]
Jan 14, 2016 5:42:23 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from resource loaded from byte array
Jan 14, 2016 5:42:23 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: User version is not explicitly defined (will use default version) [file=META-INF/ignite.xml, clsLdr=GridUriDeploymentClassLoader [urls=[file:/var/folders/t3/595tz_px2j9__wl37f0b5nw40000gn/T/gg.uri.deployment.tmp/301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0/dirzip_Archive8035449106801616883.gar/]]]
Jan 14, 2016 5:42:23 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger info
INFO: Task locally deployed: class myproject.SimpleTask
Loading SimpleTask
Computing Job in SimpleTask 
Jan 14, 2016 5:42:23 PM org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger error
SEVERE: Failed to map task jobs to nodes: GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=SimpleTaskName, dep=GridDeployment [ts=1452789743727, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=GridUriDeploymentClassLoader [urls=[file:/var/folders/t3/595tz_px2j9__wl37f0b5nw40000gn/T/gg.uri.deployment.tmp/301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0/dirzip_Archive8035449106801616883.gar/]], clsLdrId=cc234014251-301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=myproject.SimpleTask, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=1], taskClsName=myproject.SimpleTask, sesId=bc234014251-301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, startTime=1452789743638, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, clsLdr=GridUriDeploymentClassLoader [urls=[file:/var/folders/t3/595tz_px2j9__wl37f0b5nw40000gn/T/gg.uri.deployment.tmp/301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0/dirzip_Archive8035449106801616883.gar/]], closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, subjId=301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1452789743739, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, lsnr=null, state=INIT]]]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Task map operation produced no mapped jobs: GridTaskSessionImpl [taskName=SimpleTaskName, dep=GridDeployment [ts=1452789743727, depMode=SHARED, clsLdr=GridUriDeploymentClassLoader [urls=[file:/var/folders/t3/595tz_px2j9__wl37f0b5nw40000gn/T/gg.uri.deployment.tmp/301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0/dirzip_Archive8035449106801616883.gar/]], clsLdrId=cc234014251-301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, userVer=0, loc=true, sampleClsName=myproject.SimpleTask, pendingUndeploy=false, undeployed=false, usage=1], taskClsName=myproject.SimpleTask, sesId=bc234014251-301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, startTime=1452789743638, endTime=9223372036854775807, taskNodeId=301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, clsLdr=GridUriDeploymentClassLoader [urls=[file:/var/folders/t3/595tz_px2j9__wl37f0b5nw40000gn/T/gg.uri.deployment.tmp/301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0/dirzip_Archive8035449106801616883.gar/]], closed=false, cpSpi=null, failSpi=null, loadSpi=null, usage=1, fullSup=false, subjId=301a4cb8-6fc7-4aa9-b050-3083183f4cd0, mapFut=IgniteFuture [orig=GridFutureAdapter [resFlag=0, res=null, startTime=1452789743739, endTime=0, ignoreInterrupts=false, lsnr=null, state=INIT]]]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:497)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:678)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:447)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteComputeImpl.execute(IgniteComputeImpl.java:151)
    at _03GarTest.main(_03GarTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Comment: Is `IgniteConfiguration.isPeerClassLoadingEnabled()` flag set to true?

Comment: Ideally, you should have GAR file present on all nodes. If that is not the case, why not enable peer class loading and remove the GAR file altogether? Client would instantiate the task, and server would peer-load the task class definition from the client.

Comment: peerClassLoadingEnabled is set to true, but according to the docs, it should have nothing to do with GAR files. Closures work fine, we got that working, but it is too light weight for our use case. In the end, we want to 'deploy' new GAR files on running instances because there will be libraries included, for which GAR concept is perfect. Also, the GAR files are indeed deployed on all nodes, but for some reasons the tasks deployed with it are not executed.

Comment: Sven, your task returns `null` from `map()` method which is illegal. You can refer to `org.apache.ignite.examples.computegrid.ComputeTaskMapExample` in binary release or directly via link - https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ignite.git;a=blob;f=examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/computegrid/ComputeTaskMapExample.java;h=3de5293a814e527b57e3984f6d3ab96bb1b62daf;hb=HEAD

Comment: Nope, just changed my code and it did not change anything concerning the above exceptions (the task itself ran always perfectly on the client node itself, with or without returning null or a map)

Comment: Sven, can you please share your code? Map should not be `null` or empty otherwise it results to exception you updated your question with.

Comment: @Yakov I've implemented a 'real' task, with actual execution that does not return null or an empty map and it works now. If you add that to your answer as an update, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Sven, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sven,

You should configure URI deployment SPI on client node as well to make GAR deployment work properly.

When you call `compute.execute("taskName");` a lot of things have to be done locally on client prior to first request is sent to any of the node in your topology and after results start coming back. At least, Ignite should be able to get mapped jobs and be able to process results from all remote jobs and reduce all the results - please see `ComputeTask.map()` and `ComputeTask.result()` and `ComputeTask.reduce()`. So, you should be able to instantiate task on client node and that is why you should have task classes available.

I think after you configure URI deployment on client nodes you should have your code work fine.

Please post a comment here if you need any additional info.

Thanks!

UPDATE Jan, 18 2016

This is update in response to question update.

Please note that task in question returns null from map() method which is illegal. You can refer to org.apache.ignite.examples.computegrid.ComputeTaskMapExample in binary release or directly via https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=ignite.git;a=blob;f=examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/computegrid/ComputeTaskMapExample.java;h=3de5293a814e527b57e3984f6d3ab96bb1b62daf;hb=HEAD

Comment: I've tried that before also, see update in question above

Comment: Sven, see my comment to the question. You need to properly implement your task.

Comment: Note that returning an empty map is not sufficient